# How to fix "Cargo.toml not found in any /hello_world or any parent directory" Even when it is in the Correct Directory

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I was installing rust on Debian Linux using this:

```bash
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs > rust_setup.sh
chmod +x rust_setup.sh
./rust_setup.sh
sudo apt install gcc
```

And when I made a test project called hello world and tried to run it using `cargo run`, it says that it cannot find Cargo.toml even though it is in the correct directory.  I tried to rename the file using the copied name from the error, but nothing changed.  What is the problem?

Screenshots:

[image: Termnil screengrab]

EDIT:
I have found the root problem.  All of the paths start with `/home/runner/ReplRoot` rather than just `/`.  This makes it impossible for programs to get the correct path without manual direction.  This would mean that I have to set all of the paths manually rather than the program being able to infer them.  Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Did you input `cargo new hello_world` at the very beginning?

Comment: I did, I forgot to include that

Comment: `cat Cargo.toml > Cargo.toml` will delete all the contents of the `Cargo.toml` file.

Comment: Doesn't using `cargo init` from your `hello_world` directory recreate the `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: The message implies it's looking in the absolute path `/hello_world` for some reason. So something isn't setup right in your cargo project. Maybe just try starting from scratch with another `cargo new project...`.

Comment: I just restarted after deleting the old project, and the error still occurs, also running it from the parent directory does nothing (same error)

Comment: did you run command `source "$HOME/.cargo/env"` ?

Comment: I did run that, if i didn't, it would return command not found

Comment: When you have run command ./rust_setup.sh are you chose option 1? I tried on my side and i removed Cargo.toml. The error is `error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/opt/hello_world` or any parent directory` If you execute `cp Cargo.toml /Cargo.toml` it would be work. But is not the normal behavior

Comment: I chose option 1, and even after running `cp Cargo.toml /Cargo.toml`, I still get the error.

Comment: Last chance... could you run `strace cargo run` and show the output in a pastebin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249200/discussion-between-inyourface3445-and-zeppi).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely caused by linux permissions
Even `cargo new hello_world` failed to read the Cargo.toml file.
Try `sudo cargo new hello_world` and `sudo cargo run` instead.
Or check the folder permission you're working in.

Comment: When I try `sudo cargo`, I get a comman not found

Comment: @inyourface3445 use `whereis cargo` to find the its location, then `sudo fullpath/cargo run`

Comment: I should also add that i tried installing it under sudo perms, but that threw a os error for insufficient permissions to modify the privileges of a file in the root folder.

Comment: When I do that, It throws `error: not a directory: '/root/.rustup'`